# Errors were encountered while processing gdk-pixbuf-psd

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm getting this error whenever I'm installing/removing or anything else using dpkg...

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  gdk-pixbuf-psd E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried:

```
sudo dpkg -r logmein-client 
sudo apt-get install -f
```

none of them worked. Also tried to remove it using Synaptics Package Manager, but the same error happens.

what should I do to get rid of it?

EDIT: Full log for running sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
and 12 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this
operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Setting up
gdk-pixbuf-psd (20081217) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gdk-pixbuf-psd.postinst: 23:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gdk-pixbuf-psd.postinst: cannot create
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/loader-files.d/gdk-pixbuf-psd.loaders:
Directory nonexistent /var/lib/dpkg/info/gdk-pixbuf-psd.postinst: 23:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gdk-pixbuf-psd.postinst: gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders:
not found dpkg: error processing package gdk-pixbuf-psd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 127 Errors were encountered while processing:  gdk-pixbuf-psd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What are the messages before that line?

Comment: Post Edited....

Comment: didn't helped...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by editing this file:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gdk-pixbuf-psd.postinst
```

I commented line 23 (which is indicated in the error), then ran

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

successfully. After that, I removed the package using Package Manager